# Como somar valores de uma requisição json em python?

Tags: python

Exemplo:

```
request = requests.get('https://api.amountofsomething.com')
amount = request.json()['amount']
```

Esta requisição retorna valores como esses:

```
[{"amount": 0.1}, {"amount": 2},{"amount": 145},{"amount": 5.84}]
```

Eu preciso fazer somas, sem padrões, de diferentes valores do índice.
Eu tenho feito assim, e tem dado certo, mas para grandes quantidades de dados o código fica muito extenso.

```
amount0 = amount[0]['amount']

amount1 = amount[1]['amount']

amount2 = amount[2]['amount']
```

`sum0 = amount0 + amount2`  >>>  sum0 = 0.1 + 145

...

Tentei de diferentes formas, manipular esses dados para gerar menos códigos.

```
sum0 =  amount [0+2]['amount']

sum1 = amount [[0] + [2]]['amount']

sum2 = amount [0]['amount'] + amount [2]['amount']
```

Nenhuma dessas opções funcionou, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda ?

Answer (score 2):

Se a sua resposta vem da forma:

```
amounts = [{"amount": 0.1}, {"amount": 2}, {"amount": 145}, {"amount": 5.84}]
```

E você precisa somar todos os valores, basta fazer:

```
total = sum(it['amount'] for it in amounts)
```

Assim, somará independente da quantidade de itens que vem na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Condiderando que você tem uma lista de dicionários retornando nessa api temos:

```
amounts = [
        {"amount": 0.1},
        {"amount": 2},
        {"amount": 145},
        {"amount": 5.84}
    ]
```

Você poderia iterar sobre essa lista somando os indices..

```
soma = 0

for amount in amounts[0:15]:
    soma += amount.get("amount",0)
```

Ou então utilizar list comprehension

```
soma = sum(amount.get("amount",0) for amount in amounts[0:15])
```

**EDIT:** Alteração para somar apenas os 15 primeiros índices dos dados retornados.

A contagem dos itens se inicia no 0 e vai até o max-1 , no caso 15-1 = 14... Assim do índice 0 até o 14 são 15 valores.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado por responder. Com esse o código consigo o retorno da soma de todas as quantidades, mas no caso eu precisaria de somar por exemplo as 15 primeiras quantidades , teria como modificar seu código para isso ?

Comment: Alterado para a sua sugestão. Apenas adicionado a contagem de índices..

Answer (score 0):

Você possui vários dicionários dentro de uma lista, então podemos acessar esses dicionários com um for:

```
req = [{"amount": 0.1}, {"amount": 2},{"amount": 145},{"amount": 5.84}]

soma = 0
for dic in req:
    soma += dic['amount']

>>> print soma
152.94
```

Edit:

Veja bem

```
req[0] = {"amount": 0.1} #Primeiro item da lista é um dicionario
req[1] = {"amount": 2}

req[0]['amount'] = 0.1 #Assim acessamos o valor
req[1]['amount'] = 2
```

Então, para somar apenas os 2 primeiros índices, por exemplo, podemos fazer:

```
soma = 0
for i in range(0,2):
    soma += req[i]['amount']

>>> print (soma)
2.1
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, com seu código consigo a soma de todos os índices , seria possível por exemplo somar apenas os 15 primeiros índices ?

Comment: @EliezerBorges , veja a edição que fiz

Comment: Pelo seu conceito consegui resolver meu problema. Obrigado por dispor de seu tempo e conhecimento para me ajudar.